# Form input with autocompletion restricted region, department, city

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, autocomplete

I search a solution for auto complete and restricted my form for register an account with 3 input : region, department, city

I want a autocompletion and restriction for only word in suggest

I search the best way for do that

Thanks in advance

PS: its ok i have fix the problem thx all

Comment: You mean some thing like country,state,city and choose within selected value ?

Comment: You must add the code.

Comment: Nishant Dixit yes